# Kinect for windows running requirements

Tags: c#, kinect

I developed an application using Kinect sensor and installed version 1.8 SDK and everything works fine. but it fails to detect the sensor when running the executable file with only Kinect for windows runtime v1.8, So my question is, Do i have to install Kinect SDK v1.8 to run the application or Just the runtime will work ? and if it works with the runtime file, what could be the reason preventing it form working with me ?

Comment: is your executable files together with your other files?

Comment: i don't know what you mean by other files, but i put in my directory the exe and required dll files

Comment: Ill write the steps in the answers below

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have this code in the post build to copy the dll files over to the release folder you will need to run the exe file.

> Under Projects > "YourProjectName" Properties

Paste this Code under Post Build event.

```
xcopy "$(KINECTSDK20_DIR)Redist\VGB\$(Platform)\vgbtechs" "$(TargetDir)\vgbtechs" /S /R /Y /I
```

[image]

> Second, Run the program in release build first with the configuration
>   of x64 as show here.

[image]

> Third, you would create an exe file found here.

[image]

Now you can create a shortcut to be able to run the program.
IMPORTANT: the exe file must be in the release folder, you can rename it and zip it to send to other people.
[image]

Now, you are good to go, all the required dll files should be located in the folder.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: i am targeting x86 for building and it throws Error 1 The command "xcopy "Redist\VGB\x86\vgbtechs" exited with code 4

Comment: Try use x64, i know it should not matter much